# Apache Beam trigger empty window in batch job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger an empty window in my Pipeline batch job. The pipeline reads data from a BigQuery table and applies windows to partition the data into days and loads that data into a partitioned BigQuery table. Now in case the source doesn't have any data, the job never completes as there isn't a single window being triggered.

How can I force an empty window to trigger let's say after 1 minute of not receiving any data? The AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane() trigger expects at least 1 item to fire which doesn't work. I've tried adding a "heartbeat" dummy row into the process to fire the window which worked until I tried to filter it out again after the windows strategy as I obviously don't want to write it to the BigQuery table.

Anyone got an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: If there is no data read in, the pipeline should complete and produce no output. Could you share a job ID so we can try to figure out what is going on?

Comment: @BenChambers turns out the job completes when run on DataFlowRunner but doesn't complete on DirectRunner only (2017-06-20_01_08_22-5570474346450337504). It's only the stream that uses the windowing strategy that never completes.

Comment: Can you share more of your pipeline? We have tried to reproduce this and have been unable to. The DirectRunner should terminate as soon as it discovers that all of the elements (of which there were none) have been processed.